# Clear trailing 0's on a double?

Tags: c, objective-c, double, rounding

I have a double thats got a value of something like 0.50000 but I just want 0.5 - Is there any way to get rid of those trailing 0's? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

standard c format statements.

```
NSLog(@" %.2f", .5000)
```

Answer (score 13):

In C,

```
printf("%g", 0.5000);
```

Note: (from GNU libc manual)

> The **%g** and **%G** conversions print the argument in the style of *%e* or *%E* (respectively)
>   **if the exponent would be less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision**; otherwise
>   they use the ‘%f’ style. A precision of 0, is taken as 1. Trailing zeros are removed from the
>   fractional portion of the result and a decimal-point character appears only if it is followed
>   by a digit.

Comment: It works fine but it gives Exponential form for large numbers & i don't want that.. Any solution to that?