# Remove Trailing Zeros from a double (ObjectiveC)

Tags: objective-c, double, zero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear trailing 0’s on a double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641108/clear-trailing-0s-on-a-double)
>   [Limit a double to two decimal places without trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026135/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places-without-trailing-zeros)

I have a field where a user enters a number via the keyboard (decimal numberpad), for example, "1.5".  This is stored as a double.

Later when I allow the user to edit the field and present the number it is shown as "1.500000" which I don't want.

What's the most efficient method to remove these trailing zeros?  I can't round the number to a specific number of decimal points because the user can enter any number they wish and it has to stay this way (it's a unit of weight).

I could split the number into an array of characters and iterate over in reverse popping off the zeros until I hit anything above 0 but I thought/hoped there was something a little more efficient in Objective C?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit a double to two decimal places without trailing zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026135/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places-without-trailing-zeros) Also see: [Clear trailing 0s on a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641108/clear-trailing-0s-on-a-double)

Comment: ah, you beauty, the second one is perfect.  Thanks! :)